# Address warning to convert from object to string

Tags: python, warnings

I am trying to write a data frame to a `.xpt` file in Python.

I have working code, meaning the code does create a `.xpt` file, however I get these warning messages that Python is converting object to string, however I have saved them as strings. I have tried using `str()` around the column names. I tried setting `info = info.astype(str)`. I tried creating the table using `pandas`, yet I can't get away from this warning message.

```
import xport

info = {'boy': ['x'],
        'name': ['sam'],
        'sex': ['male'],
        'race': ['white']}

with open ('C:/XPT File/info.xpt','wb') as f:
    xport.from_columns(info, f)
```

This is the warning message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "~\site-packages\xport\v56.py", line 609
    warnings.warn(f'Converting column dtypes {conversions}')
UserWarning: Converting column dtypes {'boy': 'string', 'name': 'string', 'sex': 'string', 'race': 'string'}
Converting column 'boy' from object to string
Converting column 'name' from object to string
Converting column 'sex' from object to string
Converting column 'race' from object to string
```

I know it's possible to suppress the warning messages, but I would prefer not to do that. Is there a better way to code this so that there are no warning messages and if possible, no 'converting' messages either?

Comment: You could probably use `json.dumps(info['boy'])` to prepare it for export, to convert it into a string. or just do `str(info['boy'])` or something similar. Meaning, instead of letting the library do its job, you could convert to the desired data type before using `xport.from_columns(info, f)`.

Comment: thanks @Torxed, I tried ```str(info['boy'])``` before ```xport.from_columns(info, f)``` and that didn't work.